# View returns different results from its SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have a SQL view that returns fewer results than the select inside it, and I don't know why?

The SQL view code:

```
SELECT cs.customer_id, cs.store_id, cs.join_date, c.name, c.email, c.phone, cs.points,
       COALESCE (aph.added_point, 0) AS added_point,
       COALESCE (aph.spended_cash, 0) AS spended_cash
FROM dbo.customer_store AS cs 
INNER JOIN dbo.customer AS c
    ON cs.customer_id = c.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.added_points_history AS aph
    ON cs.customer_id = aph.customer_id AND cs.store_id = aph.store_id
```

The above query returns 26 rows, but when I select from the view it returns 7 rows only!

The code that created the View:

```
--Set the options to support indexed views.
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
--Create view with schemabinding.
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.customers_store_with_points', 'view') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW dbo.customers_store_with_points ;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.customers_store_with_points
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT cs.customer_id, cs.store_id, cs.join_date, c.name, c.email, c.phone, cs.points,
    COALESCE (aph.added_point, 0) AS added_point,
    COALESCE (aph.spended_cash, 0) AS spended_cash
FROM dbo.customer_store AS cs 
INNER JOIN dbo.customer AS c
ON cs.customer_id = c.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.added_points_history AS aph
ON cs.customer_id = aph.customer_id AND cs.store_id = aph.store_id
GO
--Create an index on the view.
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_customerId_storeId
ON dbo.customers_store_with_points (customer_id, store_id);
GO
```

The select statment for getting results from the View:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [dbo].[customers_store_with_points]
order by store_id
```

Comment: Please specify the query of create view.. And also the select statement on View. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Specify both view and select statement query

Comment: May I guess, the select has a left join, but the view a regular inner join.

Comment: question updated!

Comment: Just as @jarlh said.

Comment: sorry i updated it again it's the same inner query.

Comment: @KhairyAbdel-Zaher you posted views DDL with `INNER JOIN` to history and then updated it to `LEFT JOIN`. So what's the view's sql code?

Comment: It's also not the same, why aren't you using the coalesce in the view?

Comment: I'm sorry again the inner query changed I posted old view code I will change it. but they are the same in the database as i said.

Comment: Can you add `@@SERVERNAME` and `DB_NAME()` to both select clauses?  As others have stated, the root cause will be different data sources.  It's just a question of tracking down where/how this occurs.

Comment: @destination-data the fix was dropping the View and creating it again,as i was editing it from the VS designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identical queries with identical data sources returns the same results.
Either you are querying different databases or your queries are different.

Comment: Have you verified as I've asked?

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that I used the View inner code and tested outside and it resulted a different rows from the View itself.

Comment: @KhairyAbdel-Zaher, I understand that but it in which  database are you currently working?

Comment: both the query and the view are on the same database which is [KartiAppDB]

Comment: @KhairyAbdel-Zaher. I don't believe in magics. Identical queries with different results means different data sources (or you didn't gave us the right code). from [KartiAppDB] recreate the view the copy the select statement and compare them again

Comment: THANKS, Dropping the View and recreating it fixed the issue! why didn't I try that? I was editing it from VS View Designer maybe that's the problem.

Comment: the problem was fixed by recreating the view as you suggested but the database/data source were the same. but I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem now, I recreated the view (by `Script View as > DROP And CREATE To`) and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I will clarify, earlier I changed the DB name from _test_ to _test_old_ and then I duplicated _prod_ to _test_ again.
Maybe there were some dependencies left.

It can give an idea to research